# Overlay bitmap on another bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

On a single bitmap I need to display graphs and text values. So what I did is create a bitmap with points and creating a another bitmap with the text and place on the large bitmap.

I tried using the brush to write the text, but I am not able to see the underlying graphics even though trasparency is set.

Instead I thought to set the transparency for the text bitmap, but the bitmap which I have created are 24 bit rgb. So can we set the transparency for the 24 bit map.

Bitmap textBitmap = null;
  textBitmap = new Bitmap(10, 10, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

```
    using (Graphics memoryGrahics =
                     Graphics.FromImage(textBitmap))
    {

        memoryGrahics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
        memoryGrahics.DrawString(result, f, Brushes.White, x, y);
    }

    //placing the text bitmap on the graphbitmap    
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(GraphBitmap))
    {
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        textBitmap.MakeTransparent();
        g.DrawImage(textBitmap, 0, 0);
        return GraphBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: what kind of bitmap are you talking about?

Comment: The bit map which I want to create is PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb

Comment: Posting the code you have so far will help solicit answers.

Comment: how to add the code, if I add it in the comment, warning is shown too long

Comment: Try choosing a format that ends with Argb as the A stands for alpha (transparency).

Comment: without using the alpha channel, is it not possible?

Comment: When I call like this textBitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White); The text is not shown properly.

Comment: What are the values for F, x and y?

Comment: Font is arial with value 10.0f and x and y are the points calculated based on the text length and number of text

Answer (score 0):

well.. it seems like you are using 2 different Graphical objects... although 1 Graphics objects with 1 bitmap can handle **multiple** layouts of custom drawings, like so:

```
        int width = 800, height = 600;

        var bit = new Bitmap(width, height);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bit);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        var area = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        g.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(area, Color.PaleGoldenrod, Color.OrangeRed, 45), area);

        g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(@"your image"), new Point(10, 10));

        g.DrawString("sample", new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 56), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(50, 50));

        pictureBox1.Image = bit;
```

note that g.DrawImage method can be used to load other bitmaps as well